# Setting backup-permissions for C:\Users

Tags: windows-7, permissions, backuppc

I'm trying to properly setup a share for [BackupPC](http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/) to backup my user's profiles. BackupPC uses a special user `backup` to connect to each PC and backup the profiles from there. I've create a separate share on `C:\Users` giving read access to the backup user. Since the underlying NTFS permissions also play a role I've also allowed `Read & execute` for the backup user to `C:\Users`. In the "Advanced Security Settings for Users" dialog it is displayed as applying to this folder, subfolders and files.

Contrary to the permissions on `C:\Users`, the backup user cannot access the content of the profiles. BackupPC complains:

```
NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED listing \username\*
```

Also, checking the effective permissions within the folders shows no access for the backup user.

**What am I doing wrong and how can I set the permissions for the backup user so that they are inherited correctly?**

I'm running Windows 7 on the clients and the current version of BackupPC on GNU/Debian 6.0 Squeeze.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When revisiting this problem, I noticed that the actual users' profile folders do not inherit permissions from the parent directory. Setting this flag, or giving separate permissions on each profile folder, let's the backup user access the files.

Comment: I'd still be interested in any solution that doesn't involve manual steps for each new user and each new machine.

Comment: Did you reach a conclusion?  I had to manually grant permissions for Backuppc to reach my home directory, it was very ugly.  No amount of permission seemed to be enough for a BackupPC user.

Comment: I've switched to having important data in github, owncloud or on a fileserver. The hassle of backing up the profile directory is just not worth it. Especially as I'm starting to have my doubts that this will properly restore anyways, with all the ACL stuff going on and what not.